# Laravel delete in two related tables in the same time

Tags: mysql, laravel, models, delete-row

I'm trying to delete data in two related tables between themselves. So, when I delete a row in **websites** table, I also want to delete rows in **keywords** table which are related with foreign key
**websites**
id | siteName

1 | example
**keywords**
id | website_id | kwName

1 | 1          
So when I delete a website, the row with the same id(website_id as foreign key) does not deleted.

My code for delete is:
**Controller**

```
public function destroy($id)
{ 
     $projects = Website::findOrFail($id);
     $projects->delete();

    return redirect()->route('projects.index')->with('alert-success','Data Has been Deleted!');
}
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach($projectss as $projects)

    <tr>

      <td>{{$no++}}</td>
      <td>{{$projects->siteName}}</td>
      <td>{{$projects->siteUrl}}</td>       


      <td>
        <form class="" action="{{route('projects.destroy',$projects->id)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
          <a href="{{route('projects.show',$projects->id)}}" class="btn btn-success">View</a>
          <a href="{{route('projects.edit',$projects->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this data');" name="name" value="delete">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
```

**Model Keyword.php**

```
public function website() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Website');
}
```

**Model Website.php**

```
public function keywords() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Keyword');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick method you can utilize us to bind to the `boot` function in your `Website` model and then capture the `deleted` event, which provides you an instance of the model that is being deleted as the first argument `($website)`.

Here's an example:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleted(function($website){
        $website->keywords()->delete();
    });
}
```

Comment: An error: Cannot make static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::boot() non static in class App\Website

Comment: @R.Jonson I've updated the function to be static, moving too quickly. Apologies.

Comment: Great! It works. Thank you. Sorry for that error, I also had not seen the function was not with static. Many thanks once again.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to achieve this is to use `onDelete('cascade')` when defining foreign key constraint:

```
$table->foreign('website_id')->references('id')->on('websites')->onDelete('cascade');
```

So when you'll delete a website, all keywords related to it will be deleted automatically.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: I would like to be like this. I tried it, I wrote the same code in create_keywords_table.php migration, but didn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: I actually upvoted this and would prefer this method as to the answer that I provided, however, sometimes it's just easier to bind to the boot method for beginners not familiar with migrations or how Foreign Key Constraints work. Still, +1 and anyone else searching this answer should prefer their schema pattern to look like this so the application doesn't need to emulate proper database design.

Comment: I agree but, this method doesn't work in my case. I tried but it doesn't work. However, I upvoted this.

Comment: @R.Jonson did you refresh migrations or added a new migration which redefines a foreign key?

Comment: Yes, after changed the row code, I refresh(php artisan migrate:refresh),all records was removed, however it doesn't work.